# @ExceptionHandler is Not working when automatic binding fails in REST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two REST API's GET POST

When any Exception is thrown inside the method, Exception handler is working fine.
But if i use malformed REST api uri then it only shows 400 Bad Request without going to Exception Handler.

Eg.

If I hit http://localhost:8080/mypojoInteger/abc, it fails to parse string into Integer and hence I am expecting it to go to ExceptionHandler.
It does not go to Exception Handler, Instead I only see 400 Bad Request.

It works fine and goes to Exception Handler when any Exception is thrown inside the GET/POST method.

For eg: It works fine and goes to Exception Handler if I use 123 in path variable
http://localhost:8085/mypojoInteger/123

And change getData method to

```
 @GetMapping("/mypojoInteger/{sentNumber}")
    public void getData(@PathVariable("sentNumber") Integer sentNumber) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("Exception");    
    }
```

NOTE: Same issue is with POST request also.

1. GET:

```
   @GetMapping("/mypojoInteger/{sentNumber}")
   public void getData(@PathVariable("sentNumber") Integer sentNumber) {
   //some code    
   }
```

2. POST:

```
 public void postData(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) {
    //some code
  }
```

Controller Advice class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(
            NumberFormatException ex) {

         // some logic
    }
}
```

How can I handle Exception when it fails to bind String to Integer in REST API uri itself??

EDIT: My Requirement is I should handle the overflow value of integer i.e, If a pass more than maximum value of Integer it must handle it rather than throwing NumberFormatException Stack Trace.

Eg: When i pass over flow value

POJO:

```
public class MyPojo extends Exception {

    private String name;

    private Integer myInt;

//getters/setter
}
```

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "myInt":12378977977987879
}
```

Without @ControllerAdvice it just shows the NumberFormatException StackTrace.
With @ControllerAdvice it just shows 400 bad request with no Response Entity.
I do not want this default stacktrace/400 bad request in case of this scenario
but I want to show my custom message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that i see is that, because since your request itself is malformed-> the method body never gets executed - hence the exception never occurs because it is only meant to handle the error within the method . It is probably a better design choice for  you to form a proper request body rather than allowing it to execute any method so you know the problem before hand.

Comment: If user passes the overflow value of integer i.e, greater than maximum value of integer then also it fails. I want to have the functionality where if any user/hacker will pass the overflow value i would not want to reveal the stack trace saying NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `Integer` object is not sent as a `valid request parameter`, example of request: 5 if you send String an exception will be thrown directly. If you want to check if it is a String or Integer you might change your code by following this way:

```
@GetMapping("/mypojoInteger/{sentNumber}")
public void getData(@PathVariable("sentNumber") Object sentNumber) {
    if (!(data instanceof Integer)) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Exception");    
    }        
}
```

This should work on your example.

Comment: I know this workaround but I am afraid I would want to use it in POST  request. As one of the fields in POJO should contain Integer/long/BigInteger as per my business requirement. If I pass overflow value i.e, more than maximum permitted value also it acts as a Malformed REST api uri,

Comment: OK then continue using several exception handlers, the issue as I mentioned is for levels, the top level found that an `Integer` as object was not passed then first it is thrown, you can catch it, how? just check the exception and create an exception handler method or adding the current exception handler for numbers, then register or add XxxxxxxException which was displayed.String object

Comment: Yes that works fine in case if method thows Exception. Suppose you pass i.e, ```http://localhost:8085/mypojoInteger/12321342343243243443```, it is a Number but still it behaves as malformed uri as it crosses the limit of Integer and gives 400 bad request.

Comment: That is another exception, right? then you should create a new custom exception handler for that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I found out that I need to handle Bad Request. 
So, I have override

```
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    //Handle Bad Request
    }
```